# What do you do with unused well tiles after your turn?

Tags: triominos

What do you do with the tiles you pick up from the well and can't use? I know they count against you, but do they go back into the well or do they stay into your hand?

Answer (score 1):

They stay in your hand. I'm not sure if there are any *official* rules available online, but the drawing-from-a-common-pile mechanism, shared by many games (e.g. Scrabble, Ticket to Ride) permanently puts tiles/cards in your hand. If it were differently for Triominos, the rules would explicitly mention this.

Comment: A copy of the rules is available here: https://www.kookaburra.com.au/documents/instructions/ZCW4451_11.pdf

Answer (score -1):

## They Stay in your hand.

[Triominos rules](https://kookaburra.com.au/documents/instructions/ZCW4451_11.pdf):

> If you cannot or do not want to put down a matching Tri-omino, you
> MUST 'buy' a Tri-omino. You may then play this 'bought' tile in the same turn. You may do this a maximum of three
> times per turn. For every 'bought' Tri-omino you must subtract 5 points from your score. If you 'bought' 3 tiles and
> .have still not been able to put down a matching Tri-omino, you pass and end your turn. In this case an extra 10
> points have to be subtracted from your score-25 points in total. The next player goes.

[Deluxe TriOminos rules](https://www.pressmantoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Tri-Ominos.pdf):

> PICKING FROM THE “WELL”: If you can’t make a match, pick from the “well” (remaining Tri-Ominos
> that are face down). Keep these Tri-Ominos separate from the other Tri-Ominos in your hand until you pick a
> match. For each Tri-Omino picked from the well, the scorekeeper deducts 5 points from your score. After the
> deduction is made, the scorekeeper adds the total sum of points from the matching Tri-Omino to your score.
> If you can’t match any Tri-Omino in your hand and there are none in the well, ten points are deducted
> from your score and play continues.

Comment: Not sure this answers the question; nothing indicates they are asking about starting a new game.

Comment: @BradC, thanks, I mistakenly thought the OP askes about unused tiles in the end of the *round*.  Fixed the answer to address tiles you pickup in the middle of a round when you can't play any tile in your hand.

Answer (score -3):

If you have any unused tiles at the end of your turn, you can either keep them in your hand or return them to the well. If you keep them in your hand, they will count against you at the end of the game. However, if you return them to the well, you may be able to use them on future turns.

Comment: This answer would be improved by citing the rules that support this conclusion.

Comment: @doppelgreener The rules that support this conclusion can be found in the game's [instructions manual](https://www.pressmantoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Tri-Ominos.pdf). The manual states: If you can’t make a match, pick from the “well” (remaining Tri-Ominos that are face down). Keep these Tri-Ominos separate from the other Tri-Ominos in your hand until you pick a match.

Comment: If that's the rule, please [edit] your answer to quote the exact rule. Page numbers help complete the citation.